# Refresh DOM elements after ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, refresh

Here's a quick rundown of the problem I'm having:

I start off with

```
<container>
    <div id="foo"></div>
</container>
```

I then load content into the container `div` with Ajax

```
<container>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</container>
```

then reload the original back in

```
<container>
    <div id="foo"></div>
</container>
```

but I then can't target `#foo` with javascript anymore as javascript thinks it's a new element

The actual code is obviously far more complicated and I need to refresh the whole DOM after the ajax load so that I can use several elements that were previously there before hand.

Comment: So you're detaching #foo from the dom and re-attaching it later?

Comment: Where is you javascript? It is kind of hard to debug javascript when all you present is HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by "target #foo"? `document.getElementById('foo')` will work for sure if the element is in the DOM.

Comment: @Musa yes I'm replacing the contents of the container with another page, then reloading the previous page back into the container

Comment: @FelixKling I think things are getting complicated because I'm storing the element (not it's id) in an object then targeting the element from the object. The reloaded element that gets re-added to the DOM has the same id but is in fact a different element. That make sense?

Comment: @James: Yes, totally. If reloading means that you are setting the content of the container as HTML, like `container.innerHTML = '....';` then yes, it will create a new element. As I said, you can either retrieve the reference to the new element with `getElementById` or instead of setting the content as HTML, add the old element back to the DOM, like `container.appendChild(old_foo);` where `old_foo` is the reference to `#foo` you already have.

Comment: OK, thanks @Felix I'm sure I've tried something along the lines of taking the id of the element in the object and using that along with getElementById() to target the 'new' one, I forget why that didn't work, I'll need to review in the morning after some sleep. Thanks for your help, I may well ask for it again tomorrow!

Comment: @James: No problem :) Just remember to edit this question (add the information) and not create a new one... unless it is totally different. You can add a new comment so that the commenters (e.g. me ;)) get notified.

Comment: SOLVED. As you suggested @Felix, instead of taking the actual element from the object, `{playlist.track}` for example, I took the id from the object and targetted the 'new' element with it like this `document.getElementById(playlist.track.id)` I'll update my question with this answer above

Comment: Great :) If you want to I can write a proper answer (later), or you can simply delete the question, or whatever.... Either way is fine for me :) Happy coding!

Comment: Feel free to comment on my solution I added above if you think necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Question answered in the comments and by question edits. Converted to community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The problem arises because I am creating an object with the element as a variable in, so when I call that variable again, the actual element it represents no longer exists, just an element with the same id
>
> SOLVED:
>
> Thanks to a suggestion from @felix in the comments, I realised that the way to do this was to get the id of the element stored in the object variable and use that to target the new element in the ajax loaded content:
>
> My object variable created from the original content: `playlist.trackdiv` which represents the element `div#track1`
>
> when I load that `div` in later through ajax `playlist.trackdiv` no longer represents `div#track1` but a completely new instance of an element with the same id. The solution is to use the id of the object like this `playlist.trackdiv.i`d then target the new element using that: `document.getElementById(playlist.trackdiv.id)`